# Strange .NET Mail behaviour with Disposables

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, email, smtpclient

Recently been going through a bunch of code tidying up and "improving" things, I noticed this bit of code used for sending emails:

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient() With {
    .Port = 25,
    .Host = Email.Hostname,
    .Credentials = New NetworkCredential() With {
        .UserName = Email.UserName,
        .Password = Email.Password      
    }
}

Dim mail As New MailMessage() With {
    .From = Email.Sender,
    .Subject = Email.Subject,
    .IsBodyHtml = True,
    .Body = Email.WrappedHtml
}
If Not Email.Attachments Is Nothing Then
    For Each a In Email.Attachments
        mail.Attachments.Add(a)
    Next
End If    
mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(Email.Recipient.Email, Email.Recipient.Name))
Call SmtpServer.Send(mail)

SmtpServer.Dispose()
mail.Dispose()
SmtpServer = Nothing
mail = Nothing
```

In that example the `Email` Object is a Class containing basic email information, recipients, sender, attachments etc.

The code above works perfectly....

But, I noticed that `SmtpServer` and `MailMessage` are both `Disposable` objects, and it would be better practice to wrap them in `Using` statements, thus:

```
Using SmtpServer As New SmtpClient() With {
    .Port = 25,
    .Host = Email.Hostname,
    .Credentials = New NetworkCredential() With {
        .UserName = Email.UserName,
        .Password = Email.Password      
    }
    }

    Using mail As New MailMessage() With {
            .From = Email.Sender,
            .Subject = Email.Subject,
            .IsBodyHtml = True,
            .Body = Email.WrappedHtml
        }
        If Not Email.Attachments Is Nothing Then
            For Each a In Email.Attachments
                mail.Attachments.Add(a)
            Next
        End If    
        mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(Email.Recipient.Email, Email.Recipient.Name))
        Call SmtpServer.Send(mail)
    End Using
End Using
```

However... when I do that, and send more than a couple of emails in quick succession I get:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean read430) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.Read430s(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean one430) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.Read430(SmtpReplyReader caller) at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

It appears that the `Using` Statements are causing the connection to close too early....

Anyone else had similar experience/tips on solution?

I've reverted to the old code, but it is better practice to wrap in `using` statements, right?